# c# - Filtering on properties of an object in a listbox

Tags: c#, listbox, filtering

I have a question regarding a little project I'm doing. I currently have a listBox filled with objects of the type 'Game'. In Game, there are attributes like Name, GameConsole, Genre,...

I'd like to filter my results based on those attributes. I was wondering if this would at all be possible. I get my game objects via a DA-class out of an Access database.

I get my games from the DA with this bit of code:

```
listBoxGames.BeginUpdate();
DAGame daGame = new DAGame();
List<Game> games = daGame.GetGames();

foreach (Game game in games)
{
    listBoxGames.Items.Add(game);
}
listBoxGames.EndUpdate();
```

edit: Here's the declaration of my Game object

```
public Game(int id, string naam, string afbeelding, float score, string opmerkingen, bool online, bool coOp, int maxAantalSpelers, int multiplayerTypeId, int systeemId, int genreId, int jaar, bool touchControls, string uitgeleend, bool favoriet)
        {
            this.Id = id;
            this.Naam = naam;
            this.Afbeelding = afbeelding;
            this.Score = score;
            this.Opmerkingen = opmerkingen;
            this.Online = online;
            this.CoOp = coOp;
            this.MaxAantalSpelers = maxAantalSpelers;
            this.MultiplayerTypeId = multiplayerTypeId;
            this.SysteemId = systeemId;
            this.GenreId = genreId;
            this.Jaar = jaar;
            this.TouchControls = touchControls;
            this.Uitgeleend = uitgeleend;
            this.Favoriet = favoriet;
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you add declaration of you Game object? It's not clear if you mean [attributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288454(v=vs.71).aspx) or properties. But you certainly are looking for [LINQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397933.aspx). There is tons of examples on web.

Answer (score 1):

This could help I think.

```
 listBoxGames.BeginUpdate();
    DAGame daGame = new DAGame();
    List<Game> games = daGame.GetGames();

    foreach (Game game in games)
    {
        listBoxGames.Items.Add(game.Where(x => x.Name.Equals("ThisName").Single());
    }
    listBoxGames.EndUpdate();
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be what you want

```
 var nameFilterList=games.Where(x=>x.Name="SomeName").ToList();
```

Comment: That seems like a bit of code I could indeed use, but can you help me out a bit with the use of the variables? :)
I don't really know how to start implementing it.

Comment: Doesnt get really , `use of variables?`

Comment: I don't really know in what context I should use this code. What should I do with the nameFilterList variable and what's in the games variable?

Comment: same as `games` this will contains list of object of class game you can iterate through it same as u have posted in question, How would we come to know what ur requirement is really, and where u want to use it and how :)